# feeds a dataTable from a database scriptdb

Tags: database, google-apps-script

I have this code:

```
 var db = dbUtenti.getDb(); // 
 var results = db.query({TipoRecord: 'Utenti'});
 var dataSource = [["Codice", "Nome","Cognome","Data nascita", "email", "telefono"]];
 var dataRow = [];

      while (results.hasNext()) {
 var result = results.next();
   dataRow[0] = result.IdUtente;
   dataRow[1] = result.Cognome;
   dataRow[2] = result.Nome;
   dataRow[3] = result.DataNas;
   dataRow[4] = result.EmailUtente;
   dataRow[5] = result.Telefono;

   dataSource.push(dataRow.slice());
  }

  var dataRange = Charts.newDataTable()
      .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, dataSource [0] [0])
      .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, dataSource [0] [1])
      .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, dataSource [0] [2]) 
      .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, dataSource [0] [3])
      .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, dataSource [0] [4])
      .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, dataSource [0] [5])

    for (i=1;i<=dataSource.length;i++){
          dataRange.addRow([dataSource [i] [0], dataSource [i] [1], dataSource [i] [2],   dataSource [i] [3], dataSource [i] [4], dataSource [i] [5]])
         .build();
          };
```

but I get an error on the line. ".build()"
This is the error: "Failed to read property "0" from undefined"

Where am I wrong?
Thank you for help me.

raffaele

Comment: I think there is some error in datasource array.It is array inside array.

Comment: It should be var dataSource = ["Codice", "Nome","Cognome","Data nascita", "email", "telefono"];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the code below 
from:

```
 for (i=1;i<=dataSource.length;i++){
          dataRange.addRow([dataSource [i] [0], dataSource [i] [1], dataSource [i] [2],   dataSource [i] [3], dataSource [i] [4], dataSource [i] [5]])
     .build();
          };
```

to:

```
 for (i=0;i<dataSource.length;i++){
          dataRange.addRow([dataSource [i] [0], dataSource [i] [1], dataSource [i] [2],   dataSource [i] [3], dataSource [i] [4], dataSource [i] [5]])
     .build();
          };
```

This is happening because you are iterating over the vector length, check the for condition.